# Uncaught afterRender threw an error in 'lightning:input'

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, error

I have implemented Lightning QuickAction. This action works fine all the time except when I enable Debug mode for my login, it throws the following error when I click on the quick action on the record page. My component defaults an input field which lets User to overwrite it. I can see the problem is being around this lightning:input but not so clear on what the error is about.

> Uncaught afterRender threw an error in 'lightning:input' 
>   [ The required label attribute value "undefined" is invalid.]
>   throws at 
>   https://mydev.lightning.force.com/auraFW/javascript/vcyT9iZ1mU1gwOHbxxPsSg/aura_proddebug.js:38351:9.
>
> Caused by: afterRender threw an error in 
>   [ The required label attribute value "undefined" is
>   invalid.]
>   Object.assert()@https://mydev.lightning.force.com/components/lightning-utils-private.js:7:17
>   LightningInput.validateRequiredAttributes()@https://mydev.lightning.force.com/components/lightning/input.js:1623:31
>
> LightningInput.connectedCallback()@https://mydev.lightning.force.com/components/lightning/input.js:888:14'lightning:input'

Can somebody please help me to understand this error?

Comment: It appears to me there's a label attribute for that input field that has not been properly defined or that you've implicitly made the field required rather than explicitly. Once you define the label and field correctly, the error should disappear.

Comment: oh yeah! my bad, made a silly mistake on label attribute. Thanks for your help! @crmprogdev